# SAP solution manager integration with ServiceNow

Tags: python, servicenow, servicenow-rest-api, sap-solution-manager

Is there a way to integrate SAP solution manager alerts with ServiceNow to create Incidents and automate this process using python?

any python package/library/module which will help to automate SAP solution manager with ServiceNow?